# Transforming a relation to 3NF

Tags: normalization, relational-theory

I'm trying to transform the following relation to 3NF but can't figure it out. 
The relation is (a student can only have 1 major):

```
STUDENT (StuID, StuName, Major), Primary Key = {StuID}
```

I tried the following transformation, splitting it into 2:

```
STUDENT (StuID, StuName)
MAJOR (StuID, Major)
```

But I don't think it is correct because there are still anomalies. For example, if the school decides to introduce a new Major, they can't add it unless a student has selected that major.

Can someone guide me how I should proceed with this problem.

Second try:

```
STUDENT (StuID, StuName, MajorID)
MAJOR (MajorID, Major)
```

Comment: Think logically. The major has to exist so that the student can take it.... So it has to be an entity.

Comment: I posted my second try above. I introduced MajorID. I think it's ok now right? Unless I'm missing something

Comment: will there be new entry made in `MAJOR` in future?

Comment: Could be, it is not specified. That's why the first one doesn't work, because if the school decides to offer a new major, it can't be added to the table until a student chooses it.

Comment: and student can choose two `major` at a time?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is better choice when student can choose multiple `Major` at a time.

```
STUDENT (StuID, StuName)
MAJOR (StuID, Major)
```

You Second Try will be a better choice when student can choose only one `Major` at a time

```
STUDENT (StuID, StuName, MajorID)
MAJOR (MajorID, Major)
```

Now one more step, I can think of here is, as `Major`  value is some fixed set of variable(limited in number), This will gives the option to add new `Major` and student can choose more than one `Major` at a time.

```
Student (StuID, StuName)
Major (StuID, MajorID)
MajorLookup (MajorID, Major)
```

Comment: Student can only choose 1 major.

Comment: @user50887, Go with your second try, that is the best choice now.

Comment: In the scenario when a student can choose multiple majors, you said: STUDENT(StuID, StuName) and MAJOR (StuID, Major). But is this in 3NF? Because there is a multivalued variable. StuID appears in both relations, so you need to update StuID in two places, no?

Comment: Yes, it is 3NF, as let say a student choose 2 major, then there will be only one entry in `STUDENT` table and two entry in `MAJOR` table. on update, it depends what you need to update only `StuName` then update only `STUDENET` table, and similar for `MAJOR` table, for updating both you need to update both table. If `STUDENT` table has 1-2 columns only, then you may go for adding mutiple reords in `STUDENT` table with column `MAJOR` added there. But Possibly you may have more columns in `STUDENT` table like `DateOfBirth` etc...